# Steps to create TWO NEW EC2 INSTANCE which has SAME SUBNET for primary IP

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

My main requirement is to set up two new ec2 instance with in same AZ and VPC with both of their Primary IP having same subnet.

Additionally if possible when  I allocate new ELASTIC IP, They also should be in same subnet range.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over the range of a Public IP address or Elastic IP address.

A **random** address will be assigned out of a pool of available IP addresses.

I presume that your desire is to be able to whitelist a *range* of IP addresses rather than having to specify them individually. A strategy for meeting this requirement is to put the instances in a **private subnet**, then put a **NAT Gateway in the public subnet**. All traffic from the instances will then come from the Elastic IP address associated with the NAT Gateway.

Another option is to [Bring Your Own IP Addresses (BYOIP) - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-byoip.html), which would then allow you to assign your own specific IP addresses to the instances.

Comment: Here in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906244/how-to-allocate-generate-new-ip-address-in-ec2-instance-in-same-subnet-range/54927281#54927281  i have answered this question.